# How to find out what the mistake is in this sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I have the following sentence. One of the bold words is used in a wrong way, so what is the mistake and how to correct it?

**That** is spurred the great explorations of the fifteenth and sixteenth centuries was the desire **to find** a **more expeditious** route to **the spice** supplies of the Far East

Comment: Is it ***That** is spurred* or ***That** spurred* in your original exercise?

Answer (score 1):

The first two words in the sentence are incorrect. I can't think of any construction to replace just the first word. One could perhaps write:

> The main economic force that spurred the great explorations of the
>   fifteenth and sixteenth centuries was the desire to find a more
>   expeditious route to the spice supplies of the Far East.

Answer (score 0):

I Think we can remove" That " from the sentence and so far start it that way 
" The great explorations of the fifteenth and sixteenth spurred in(to) the desire to find a more expeditious route to the spice supplies in the Far East"

But as in the first answer proposed is better.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest correction is to change "That is" to "What" :

> What spurred the great explorations of the fifteenth and sixteenth centuries was the desire to find a more expeditious route to the spice supplies of the Far East.